# Optimal way of declaring DI objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I've got a .net API and my Program.cs has started to become quite bloated with the following:

```
.
.
.
//core mappers
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAppData_Mapper, AppData_Mapper>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUserData_Mapper, UserData_Mapper>();

//pylon export services
builder.Services.AddTransient<IPylonItemExportService, PylonItemExportService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IPylonContactExportService, PylonContactExportService>();

//pylon repositories
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IPylonContactRepository, PylonContactRepository>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IPylonConnectionRepository, PylonConnectionRepository>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IPylonItemRepository, PylonItemRepository>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IPylonContactExportRepository, PylonContactExportRepository>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IPylonItemExportRepository, PylonItemExportRepository>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IPylonDocumentRepository, PylonDocumentRepository>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IPylonCentLineRepository, PylonCentLineRepository>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IPylonComEntryRepository, PylonComEntryRepository>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IPylonSupplierRepository, PylonSupplierRepository>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IPylonCustomerRepository, PylonCustomerRepository>();

//pylon sync services
builder.Services.AddTransient<IPylonItemSyncService, PylonItemSyncService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IPylonContactSyncService, PylonContactSyncService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IPylonMeasurementunitSyncService, PylonMeasurementunitSyncService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IPylonDocEntrySyncService, PylonDocEntrySyncService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IPylonCentLineSyncService, PylonCentLineSyncService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IPylonCommEntrySyncService, PylonCommEntrySyncService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IPylonCustomerSyncService, PylonCustomerSyncService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IPylonSupplierSyncService, PylonSupplierSyncService>();
.
.
.
```

What would be the optimal way to move these outside of my program.cs? Ideally i'd like for them to be in a seperate class that will be called via the Program.cs

- Can I pass the builder to a static method that will add the services?
- Can I create the array of services and do something like Services.AddRange?

I'm fairly new to the DI architecture on .net and any guidelines would be grately appreciated!

Comment: "yes" to both of your bullet point question. no answer on what the "optimal" way is, because that's 100% subjective.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann , thanks for the reply! how would you approach this?

Comment: You could have a class handling all registrations where you pass in the builder, this gets it out of program.cs and into its own class. It also looks like most of your registrations follow the same conventions, so perhaps a scanner for automatically connecting ISomeThing with SomeTing

Comment: @SecurityObscurity personally, i have all my services implement `IScopedService<TServiceInterface>`, any a startup-helper that auto-registers all those implementations via reflection.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Sounds clean , but a bit over my knowledge , if its no trouble I'd love some documentation - examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your first question you can move the service registration to another class by creating a new class and having the method take in the `builder` and register services then return or create an extension method. Creating an extension method is slightly "neater" and you can do it like so.

```
public static class MyServiceExtension
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddMyServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // add your services


        return services;
    }
}
```

Now in your `Program.cs` all you'll do is.

```
builder.Services.AddMyServices();
```

Comment: looks great , do I have to declare that it's an extension method somewhere?

Comment: no, you don't all you'll do is import its namespace; `using MyService.WhereItIsLocated`